# Silverlight Custom effect, get parent

Tags: c#, silverlight, shader, effect, visualtreehelper

I am trying to create a custom effect by inheriting from [Effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.effect%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
<Ellipse Width="75" Height="75" Stroke="LightGray">
    <Ellipse.Effect>
        <local:GlowEffect GlowRadius="10"/>
    </Ellipse.Effect>
</Ellipse>
```

The problem is in my effect code. I have no way of getting the parent of the effect property, in this case, that ellipse. You cannot use [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) as the ellipse will not have been loaded in the visual tree when the GlowEffect is constructed (in its constructor). I have not found a way to get by this issue, or maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way.

Comment: you can try adding `x:Name=""` to the parent and then use ElementName binding

Comment: That would not work, because the name could change from user to user. The purpose of this is to build a general-use Effect, not having to rely on made up conventions. There has to be a set way to do this, how did Microsoft do it with the BlurEffect class...?

Answer (score 0):

All "Magic" is implemented in shader file (.fx extension), but not in C# Effect class.
You have access to all pixels and their colors in shader, and you can combine colors of neighbour pixels as you wish.

```
sampler2D input : register(S0);
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD) : COLOR
{
   // access to current pixel
   float4 color1 = tex2D(input, uv);

   // access to neighbour pixel
   float2 offset = (some value);
   float4 color2 = tex2D(input, uv + offset);

   return (any formula based on color1 and color2);
}
```

I recommend you to read [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/99565575/HLSL-and-Pixel-Shaders-for-XAML-Developers) if you plan to create custom effects.

**And answer to your question is - you not need to get access to Parent element.**

Comment: That is fine, however, I am not looking to make a ShaderEffect. ShaderEffects are not supported by Silverlight for Windows Phone. Like BlurEffect, ShaderEffect is a subclass of Effect, I want to make another custom type of effect, like BlurEffect.